# Как проверить на наличие LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER?

Tags: android, gps

Нужно узнать есть ли в устройстве GPS! Как это сделать?

Comment: Вам нужно проверить, если на телефоне именно gps, или просто хочется получать координаты с хорошей точностью? ведь может быть ГЛОНАСС или Галилео.

Comment: @KoVadim именно gps и если его нет, выполнить действия соответствующие.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

используя класс [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) и его метод  getAllProviders (или  getProviders), получаем список имен всех доступных провайдеров. Дальше, в цикле, используя метод getProvider по имени провайдера получаем ссылку на класс[LocationProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationProvider.html). У него есть метод requiresSatellite - который и намекает, нужны ли спутники.

Просматривая код примеров адроида, нашел такой способ

```
LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
bool isGpsPresent = mLocationMagager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) != null;
```

Очень похоже на то, что Вам нужно, но гарантировать 100% не могу.

Comment: То, что нужно! спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Есть ещё один способ, стандартный для проверки наличия в устройстве определенных возможностей.

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
boolean hasGps = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS);
```